# Spring 4/Java Config/ RestController not found when called. "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI"

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a working web application that uses Spring 4 and java configuration. I have not had a single issue so far with this but when I went to add a quick api rest controller it flips out on me. I am sure it is some small config issue that I am missing but I just don't see it. I know that when I had worked with xml config in the past that I would use a different servlet with a different path (eg "/*" for the jsp based components and "/ws/*" for web-services) But I do not see anywhere to do that in java config and from what I have read it is not needed.

I have been trying to reach localhost:8080/scc/summaryupdate/getstats I have tried both in browser and as a wget call.

Thanks for any help you can give!

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.scc.app.dao.scriptDAO;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/summaryupdate")
public class SummaryUpdateService {
    @Autowired
    private scriptDAO dao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getstats", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public String  getStatsUpdate(){
        System.out.println("calling service.");
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Root Spring Config

```
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.scc.config.SpringRootConfig;
import com.scc.config.SpringWebConfig;

public class SCCWebInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

This is the WebConfig
        import javax.sql.DataSource;

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

    import com.scc.app.dao.UserDAO;
    import com.scc.app.dao.UserDAOImpl;
    import com.scc.app.dao.doctorDAO;
    import com.scc.app.dao.doctorDAOImpl;
    import com.scc.app.dao.scriptDAO;
    import com.scc.app.dao.scriptDAOImpl;

    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
    import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

    @EnableWebMvc //<mvc:annotation-driven />
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan({ "com.scc" })
    @Import({WebSecurityConfig.class})
    public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        }

        @Bean
        public Inte

rnalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver 
                         = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    .....Custom daos and the datasource
    }
```

Comment: Which uri are you trying to reach and how? from the browser?

Comment: Please add the URL that you're trying to reach

Comment: localhost:8080/scc/summaryupdate/getstats

I have tried both in browser and as a wget